# How to set a maximum width to a specific bar in a column/bar series in ag-charts?

Tags: angular, bar-chart, ag-grid, angular-chart

I am creating a dynamic chart using `ag-charts` wherein sometimes only a single label or value is there in the `x-axis`. In that case the bar in the chart becomes really thick and huge and doesn't appear very user friendly (as shown in the figure).

I would like to fix a `maximum width` to the bars in such a way that irrespective of the number of bars in the chart, the width should not go beyond a particular value. I have tried many approaches, like adding `maxWidth`, `barPercentage` etc, but nothing seems to be working.

```
const options = {
  container: document.getElementById('myChart'),
  title: {
    text: "Apple's revenue by product category",
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'in billion U.S. dollars',
  },
  data: getData(),
  series: [
    {
      type: 'column',
      xKey: 'quarter',
      yKey: 'iphone',
    },
  ],
};
```

[image]

I tried using maxWidth, barPercentage but nothing seems to be working. I want to decrease the width of the bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with these values

```
series: [
  {
    type: 'column',
    xKey: 'quarter',
    yKey: 'iphone',
    // PLAY WITH THESE VALUES
    strokeWidth: 35,
    lineDash: [0,2],
  },
]
```

> **strokeWidth**
> The width in pixels of the stroke for the columns.

> **lineDash**
> Defines how the column strokes are rendered. Every number in the array specifies the length in pixels of alternating dashes and gaps. For example, [6, 3] means dashes with a length of 6 pixels with gaps between of 3 pixels.

[image: Result]

Plunker:

https://plnkr.co/plunk/4TJgEDmy8V2wRE0h

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. While playing with the strokewidth and linedash properties, the bars start rising above the x-axis. Is there any way to shift the bars to coincide with the line of the x-axis?